# Searching text to see if a user enters an address (Location eg 300 Yale Street, New York)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am curious if there is a way to scan a chunk of text  to see if they entered an address. I have done some research but I am coming up shy of any results. I have seen it on iphone applications like their Notes app but can't find anything with android.

**UPDATE**

Scan a chunk of text for the address.

Comment: Try looking it up in Google Maps.

Comment: If you mean scan some text and pull out phone numbers and street addresses, I think Apple owns a patent for something like this, which might limit usage?

Comment: @JamesSugrue That was not the answer I was looking to see lol.  Okay well I guess I will have to deal with it if that is the case.

Comment: Google Places API, maybe?  https://developers.google.com/places/android/

Comment: @jyoon I will do some research

Comment: @1.618 I will have a look and comment back to see if I find anything within the api

Comment: Do you mean you want to select an adress only from a large chunk of text or its only a supposed address and you want to get a location for it?